# Blank value in web service for Int64 type

Tags: web-services, delphi, soap, null, delphi-xe2

I consume a web service that has a numeric element. The Delphi wsdl importer sets it up as Int64.

The web service allows this element to be blank. However, because it is defined as Int64, when I consume the web service in Delphi without setting a value for it, it defaults to 0 because it's an Int64. But I need it to be blank and the web service will not accept a value of 0 (0 is defined as invalid and returns an error by the web service).

How can I pass a blank value if the type is Int64?

Comment: Tell the service provider that they should fix their service? A `blank` is not a valid value for an `Int64` (and using an `Int64` for a person's age is pretty ridiculous in the first place - not many people live longer than what a `byte` can hold, at least since Biblical times).

Comment: Maybe you can try 999 as the age

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Empty age (example)

```
<E06_14></E06_14>
```

could have a special meaning, for example be "unknown" age.

In this case, the real question is how to make the field nillable on the Delphi side.

From [this post](http://www.delphigroups.info/2/12/678923.html) of J.M. Babet:

> Support for 'nil' has been an ongoing issue. Several built-in types of
>   Delphi are not nullable. So we opted to use a class for these cases
>   (not elegant but it works). So with the latest update for Delphi 2007
>   I have added several TXSxxxx types to help with this. Basically:
>   TXSBoolean, TXSInteger, TXSLong, etc. TXSString was already there but
>   it was not registered. Now it is. When importing a WSDL you must
>   enable the Use 'TXSString for simple nillable types' option to make
>   the importer switch to TXSxxxx types. On the command line it is the
>   "-0z+" option.

The [DocWiki for the Import WSDL Wizard](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Import_WSDL_Wizard) also shows two options related to nillable elements:

> - **Process nillable and optional elements** - Check this option to make the WSDL importer generate relevant information about optional
>     and nillable properties. This information is used by the SOAP runtime
>     to allow certain properties be nil.
> - **Use TXSString for simple nillable types** - The WSDL standard allows simple types to be nil, in Delphi or NULL, in C++, while Delphi
>     and C++ do not allow that. Check this option to make the WSDL importer
>     overcome this limitation by using instances of wrapper classes.

Comment: I tried that option but the wsdl importer still imports it as Int64. There must be something in the wsdl telling the importer that it's not nilable. I tried changing the imported unit definition for E06_14 to TXSInteger but couldn't find a way to make TXSInteger a nil value. Maybe I'll try changing it to TXSString and see if I have better luck.

Comment: I modified the imported unit and changed the type from Int64 to TXSInteger. Then, I set it to nil instead of instantiating TXSInteger. Works great now.