# How can Delphi understand a nillable int through SOAP?

Tags: c#, delphi, soap, wsdl

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Blank value in web service for Int64 type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12434202/blank-value-in-web-service-for-int64-type)

I have a WebService made with c# and it needs to be accessible through a Delphi Desktop application.

```
  <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="ParamName" nillable="true" type="s:int" />
```

But looks like Delphi can't handle nillable int defined in WSDL. How can I do this?

Comment: Use the XsInteger data type. This is a WSDL importer option.

Comment: Check out this StackOverFlow posting to give you some ideas 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2473051/delphi-soap-envelope-and-wcf

Comment: @DJKRAZE I sent this to my Delphi mate. He will try too. I will post resuls later.

Comment: @mjn Can't find that option. They are using Delphi 2007. It matters?

Comment: See my answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12434202/blank-value-in-web-service-for-int64-type/12435034#12435034

Comment: @mjn I'll try next Monday. Hope it really works on Delphi 7 like mentioned.

Comment: Sorry @mjn but they gave up. They don't have same pleasure to code like us guys. Thanks