# How can I import a WSDL with TSXxxx types by default?

Tags: delphi, wsdl, delphi-xe6

I consume a web service that has a numeric element. The Delphi wsdl importer sets it up as an integer.

The web service allows this element to be nullable. I checked on the other posts to find that I had to use the WSDL importer option 'Use 'TXSString for simple nillable types' ([Blank value in web service for Int64 type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12434202/blank-value-in-web-service-for-int64-type)). My only question is how can I make the WSDL importer replace the basic types (integer in my example) without any changes from me ?

With the option checked, I get my function as this :

```
function  getCode(const login: string; const password: string): Integer; stdcall;
```

And it's on me to change to :

```
function  getCode(const login: string; const password: string): TXSInteger; stdcall;
```

Any option that I forgot to make the importer use the TXSxxx types by default ?

Comment: Did you check the option "Process nillable and optional elements"?

Comment: Where can I find this option ? It does not appear to be in the importer options when I try to import the WSDL. I just have the  'Use 'TXSString for simple nillable types' option.

Comment: Please include your actual delphi version in the tags, it is important information.

Comment: I currently use Embarcadero Delphi XE6 (20.0.16277.1276)

Comment: In XE7 I have as the FIRST option "Process nillable and optional elements (-Oa)"

Comment: Ok, I just looked & I have it too. I checked but I had the same result.

Comment: Do you have found a solution for that? I am stuck on the same problem now!